# Inconsistency with inttypes.h, fscanf(), fprintf()

Tags: c, scanf, stdint

I'm having some problems with inttypes, illustrated here by this tiny code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


void print_byte(uint8_t b)
{
    printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d\n",
        !!(b & 128), !!(b & 64), !!(b & 32), !!(b & 16),
        !!(b & 8), !!(b & 4), !!(b & 2), !!(b & 1));
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    uint8_t bs = 8;
    uint16_t bw = 100, bh = 200;
    f = fopen("out", "w+");

    print_byte(bs);
    printf("%"PRIu8" %"PRIu16" %"PRIu16"\n", bs, bw, bh);
    fprintf(f, "%"PRIu8"%"PRIu16"%"PRIu16, bs, bw, bh);
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen("out", "r");

    fscanf(f, "%"SCNu8"%"SCNu16"%"SCNu16, &bs, &bw, &bh);   
    printf("%"PRIu8" %"PRIu16" %"PRIu16"\n", bs, bw, bh);
    print_byte(bs);
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Gives me

```
gcc -o test test.c && ./test
00001000
8 100 200
104 100 200
01101000
```

If I change the `SCNu8` to `SCNo8` in the fscanf, I get what I'm supposed to get:

```
00001000
8 100 200
8 100 200
00001000
```

Where is the problem? I don't see why it doesn't work for the first code, but works when I interpret that byte as an octal value.

Comment: This problem also occurs if I use `"%hhu%hu%hu"` everywhere.

Comment: The `scan`ner functions are tricky beasts. You want to test the result they return.

Comment: Also reset the three test variables to 0 before reading and get enlightened ... ;-)

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. I still don't understand why the spaces are needed.

Comment: When `scanf()` is processing an integer conversion, it scans characters that could be part of the number (unless you've specified a length: `"%1" PRIu8` will read just a single digit, but `"%" PRIu8` will read until a non-digit), and then converts the resulting string.  If overflow occurs, you get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I get it now. I guess I'll writck with the fwrite/read ones for this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the values in your *text* file end up being merged together, like this:

```
8100200
```

That is why you cannot read the data back correctly: `fscanf` does not know where the first number ends and the next number starts.

Putting spaces into the `fprintf` format line fixes this problem:

```
fprintf(f, "%"PRIu8" %"PRIu16" %"PRIu16, bs, bw, bh);
```

> [`fscanf` is] supposed to read a 1 byte value then two 2 bytes

`fscanf` reads text, not bytes. If you would like to write bytes, use library functions for binary output and input, i.e. `fwrite` and `fread`:

```
// Writing in binary
f = fopen("out.bin", "wb");
fwrite(&bs, sizeof(bs), 1, f);
fwrite(&bw, sizeof(bw), 1, f);
fwrite(&bh, sizeof(bh), 1, f);
fclose(f);
// Reading in binary
f = fopen("out.bin", "rb");
fread(&bs, sizeof(bs), 1, f);
fread(&bw, sizeof(bw), 1, f);
fread(&bh, sizeof(bh), 1, f);
```

Comment: I don't really understand you, here. Why would fscanf need a delimiter? He's supposed to read a 1 byte value then two 2 bytes one.

Comment: @user3618511: What would you expect the code to read with `bs = 1; bw = 2; bh = 3`?

Comment: Well, what I wrote: 1 2 and 3.